# LEFT JOIN in MS-Access with multiple match criteria (AND(OR)) bogging down

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I'm working in MS-Access from Office 365.

t1 is a table with about 1,000 rows.  I'm trying to LEFT JOIN t1 with t2 where t2 has a little under 200k rows.  I'm trying to match up rows using Short Text strings in multiple fields, and all the relevant fields are indexed.  The strings are relatively short, with the longest fields (the street fields) being about 15 characters on average.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT one.ID, two.ACCOUNT
FROM split_lct_2 AS one LEFT JOIN split_parcel AS two 
ON (
nz(one.mySTREET) = nz(two.pSTREET)
OR nz(one.mySTREET_2) = nz(two.pSTREET)
OR nz(one.mySTREET_3) = nz(two.pSTREET)
) 
AND (nz(one.myDIR) = nz(two.pDIR)) 
AND (nz(one.myHOUSE) = nz(two.pHOUSE));
```

The query works, however it behaves like a 3-year-old.  The query table appears after several seconds, but remains sluggish indefinitely.  For example, selecting a cell in the talble takes 3-7 seconds.  Exporting the query table as a .dbf takes about 8 minutes.

My concern is that this is just a sample file to build the queries, the actual t1 will have over 200k rows to process.

Is there a way to structure this query that will significantly improve performance?

Comment: have you tried cross join and then add where conditions with is null?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help but

```
(
nz(one.mySTREET) = nz(two.pSTREET)
OR nz(one.mySTREET_2) = nz(two.pSTREET)
OR nz(one.mySTREET_3) = nz(two.pSTREET)
)
```

is the same as

```
nz(two.pSTREET) IN (nz(one.mySTREET),nz(one.mySTREET_2),nz(one.mySTREET_3))
```

it might be the optimizer can handle this better.

Comment: I gave it a try, seems to behave about the same (without measurement).

Answer (score 0):

Definetely, joining tables using text fields is not something You are hoping for.

But, life is life.

If there is no possibility to convert text strings into integers (for example additional table with street_name and street_id), try this:

```
SELECT one.ID, two.ACCOUNT
FROM split_lct_2 AS one LEFT JOIN split_parcel AS two 
ON (nz(one.mySTREET) = nz(two.pSTREET)) 
AND (nz(one.myDIR) = nz(two.pDIR)) 
AND (nz(one.myHOUSE) = nz(two.pHOUSE))

UNION

SELECT one.ID, two.ACCOUNT
FROM split_lct_2 AS one LEFT JOIN split_parcel AS two 
ON (nz(one.mySTREET_2) = nz(two.pSTREET)) 
AND (nz(one.myDIR) = nz(two.pDIR)) 
AND (nz(one.myHOUSE) = nz(two.pHOUSE)

UNION

SELECT one.ID, two.ACCOUNT
FROM split_lct_2 AS one LEFT JOIN split_parcel AS two 
ON (nz(one.mySTREET_3) = nz(two.pSTREET)
) 
AND (nz(one.myDIR) = nz(two.pDIR)) 
AND (nz(one.myHOUSE) = nz(two.pHOUSE));
```

Comment: This is throwing a syntax error, haven't figured it out yet, but will report back if I do.

Comment: Ok. So please try to execute only first part, then second and third separately. Total query time should be the sum of 1st, 2nd and 3rd, roughly speaking.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose using Nz() does not allow to use index. Try to avoid them. If data has no NULLs in join key fields then Nz() should be safely removed from query and it should help. But if data has NULLs, you probably need to change this - for example to replace all NULLs with empty strings to make them join-able without Nz() - that's additional data processing outside of this query.

Comment: Roger that, unfortunately the nulls are present in each field.